# Trying to add a fixed vat(tax) of 5% to invoice

Tags: javascript, html, css

//The format of the code is correct and have no problem in my part and I hope it works fine with you.

I just need help with adding the vat (tax) 5% fixed and I would like it to appear on the row only the amount of the tax and then in the total tax the total of all tax and the final total would include the total of everything,  thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#addrow').click(function(){
    $('.item-row:last').after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><textarea class="cost">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="vat 5%">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td> </tr>')
    bind();
  })
bind() ;
 function bind(){
    $('.cost').blur(update_price);
    $('.qty').blur(update_price);
  }


function  update_price(){
     var row =  $(this).parents('.item-row');
     var cost =  row.find('.cost').val();
     var qty =  row.find('.qty').val();
     row.find('.price').html(Number(qty) * Number(cost) );
     update_total()
  }
function update_total(){

  var total = 0 ; 
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price =  $(this).html();
      if(price > 0){
        total += Number(price);
      }
  })
 
  $('#subtotal').html(total);
  $('#total').html(total);
}
  $('.delete').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total() ;
    
  })
})
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #222; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { width: 250px; height: 150px; float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: right; position: relative; margin-top: 25px; border: 1px solid #fff; max-width: 540px; max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
#logo:hover, #logo.edit { border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 0px; max-height: 125px; }
#logoctr { display: none; }
#logo:hover #logoctr, #logo.edit #logoctr { display: block; text-align: right; line-height: 25px; background: #eee; padding: 0 5px; }
#logohelp { text-align: left; display: none; font-style: italic; padding: 10px 5px;}
#logohelp input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.edit #logohelp { display: block; }
.edit #save-logo, .edit #cancel-logo { display: inline; }
.edit #image, #save-logo, #cancel-logo, .edit #change-logo, .edit #delete-logo { display: none; }
#customer-title { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }

#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }

#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
 
 <title>Invoice</title>

 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/custom.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

 <div id="page-wrap">

  <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea> 
  
  <div id="identity">
  
            <textarea id="address">
            text
      text
   </textarea>

  </div>
  
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div id="customer">
            <table id="meta">
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td><input type="number" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <th><label for="start"> date:</label></th>

                   <th><input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
                          value="2018-07-22"
                          min="2018-01-01" max="2030-12-31"></th>
                </tr>
             

            </table>
  
  </div>
  
  <table id="items">
  
    <tr>
        <th>unit </th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>VAT 5%</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">x</a></div></td>

        <td><textarea class="cost">0.00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="VAT">0.00</textarea></td>
        <td><span class="price">0.00</span></td>
    </tr>
 
    
    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">+</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="tax-line">tax</td>
        <td class="tax-value"><div id="tax">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="total">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <div id="terms">
   
  </div>
 
 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, I think you wanted to calculate the tax value and add it to the total.

I think this would work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#addrow').click(function(){
    $('.item-row:last').after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><textarea class="cost">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="vat 5%">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price">0</span></td> </tr>')
    bind();
  })
bind() ;
 function bind(){
    $('.cost').blur(update_price);
    $('.qty').blur(update_price);
  }


function  update_price(){
     var row =  $(this).parents('.item-row');
     var cost =  row.find('.cost').val();
     var qty =  row.find('.qty').val();
     row.find('.price').html(Number(qty) * Number(cost) );
     update_total()
  }
function update_total(){

  var total = 0 ; 
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price =  $(this).html();
      if(price > 0){
        total += Number(price);
      }
  })
  var tax = total * 0.05;
  $('#subtotal').html(total);
  $('#tax').html(tax);
  $('#total').html(total+tax);
}
  $('.delete').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
    update_total() ;
    
  })
})
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
#page-wrap { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

textarea { border: 0; font: 14px Georgia, Serif; overflow: hidden; resize: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#header { height: 15px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0; background: #222; text-align: center; color: white; font: bold 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-decoration: uppercase; letter-spacing: 20px; padding: 8px 0px; }

#address { width: 250px; height: 150px; float: left; }
#customer { overflow: hidden; }

#logo { text-align: right; float: right; position: relative; margin-top: 25px; border: 1px solid #fff; max-width: 540px; max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
#logo:hover, #logo.edit { border: 1px solid #000; margin-top: 0px; max-height: 125px; }
#logoctr { display: none; }
#logo:hover #logoctr, #logo.edit #logoctr { display: block; text-align: right; line-height: 25px; background: #eee; padding: 0 5px; }
#logohelp { text-align: left; display: none; font-style: italic; padding: 10px 5px;}
#logohelp input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.edit #logohelp { display: block; }
.edit #save-logo, .edit #cancel-logo { display: inline; }
.edit #image, #save-logo, #cancel-logo, .edit #change-logo, .edit #delete-logo { display: none; }
#customer-title { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; float: left; }

#meta { margin-top: 1px; width: 300px; float: right; }
#meta td { text-align: right;  }
#meta td.meta-head { text-align: left; background: #eee; }
#meta td textarea { width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; }

#items { clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee; }
#items textarea { width: 80px; height: 50px; }
#items tr.item-row td { border: 0; vertical-align: top; }
#items td.description { width: 300px; }
#items td.item-name { width: 175px; }
#items td.description textarea, #items td.item-name textarea { width: 100%; }
#items td.total-line { border-right: 0; text-align: right; }
#items td.total-value { border-left: 0; padding: 10px; }
#items td.total-value textarea { height: 20px; background: none; }
#items td.balance { background: #eee; }
#items td.blank { border: 0; }

#terms { text-align: center; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#terms h5 { text-transform: uppercase; font: 13px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 0 0 8px 0; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
#terms textarea { width: 100%; text-align: center;}

textarea:hover, textarea:focus, #items td.total-value textarea:hover, #items td.total-value textarea:focus, .delete:hover { background-color:#EEFF88; }

.delete-wpr { position: relative; }
.delete { display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; position: absolute; background: #EEEEEE; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 3px; border: 1px solid; top: -6px; left: -22px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
 
 <title>Invoice</title>

 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/custom.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

 <div id="page-wrap">

  <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea> 
  
  <div id="identity">
  
            <textarea id="address">
            text
      text
   </textarea>

  </div>
  
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div id="customer">
            <table id="meta">
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td><input type="number" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <th><label for="start"> date:</label></th>

                   <th><input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
                          value="2018-07-22"
                          min="2018-01-01" max="2030-12-31"></th>
                </tr>
             

            </table>
  
  </div>
  
  <table id="items">
  
    <tr>
        <th>unit </th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>VAT 5%</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">x</a></div></td>

        <td><textarea class="cost">0.00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="VAT">0.00</textarea></td>
        <td><span class="price">0.00</span></td>
    </tr>
 
    
    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">+</a></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="tax-line">tax</td>
        <td class="tax-value"><div id="tax">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="total">0.00</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <div id="terms">
   
  </div>
 
 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey, thank you so much for this, there is one more thing i hope you can help me with, what i want it to do is when i add the inputs in the invoice and print it i want the program to open another page showing, invoice no., unit and quantity. and it wil be fixed with the same information of the original invoice.